# Connect 2 virtual machines in vmware like this?

Tags: server, client, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I never tried something like this so, sorry if i'm a noob but this is what i'm trying to do:
I'm trying to connect 2 virtual machines for malware analysis. 
One machine is running kali with inetsim (which works)
but i'm trying to make my other virtual machine that is running windows xp connect to the same local host(i think xD) basically, when i connect to 127.0.0.1 from the windows machine i want it to show the inetsim website running on kali(in the kali machine, when i connect to 127.0.0.1 it works. sorry if i'm not clear.

I tried connecting both machines to VMnet0 but it doesn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem. I had to modify the inetsim config file to the vm's ip address and not the 127.0.0.1 address.

Answer (score 0):

Can provide what software you are using? For example VMWare Workstation or Fusion along with the version, this will help to narrow the problem.

From what I gather you have 2 VM's one is Kali Linux and the other is the target machine. If you want them to be on the same network I suggest you try setting both IP's of the VM to be a private class such has 10.10.1.2 and 10.10.1.3 with a 255.255.255.0 subnet. Then reboot both VM's